# JNA Issue - Only portions of an array populating from Java is used by DLL

Tags: java, jna

I am newbie to Java and JNA. I am using JNA to load and use native DLL functions from Java.

I am facing a problem in passing a pointer to an array. As per the the spec, I am populating this array from Java and trying to send a pointer to this array to the DLL.

This is how the native call looks,

```
StartCom(UNUM8 *pCoPData)
From the spec: pCoPData -> Reference of the buffer holding the data
```

Correspoding JNA Mapping,

```
    int[] buf = new int[2];
    buf[0] = 0x1A;
    buf[1] = 0x10;

    Pointer pCoPData = new Memory(8);
    pCoPData.write(0, buf, 0, buf.length);

            Library.INSTANCE.StartCom(pCoPData);
```

When I execute the above code I notice from the dll log that **only the first element of the array 0x1A is used and the second byte is ignored**. The DLL always sees only the first element of the array.

I am assuming there could be only 2 possibilies for this issue could occur,

```
  1. The above approach I have taken to populate and send the address of a Java array  to the DLL is incorrect.
  2. The DLL is expecting a UNUM8* whereas I am sending a UNUM32*. I will try with byte[] instead of int[] and see if there is any difference.
```

**Any suggestion is of great help ? Please let me know. Many thanks in advance !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you expect proper results when you pass the function incorrect types on input?

If the function is expecting a pointer to one or more 8-bit elements (`byte` in Java, presumably `UNUM8` is 8 bits in your native code), then you need to pass the equivalent of a pointer to one or more 8-bit elements.  You are passing a pointer to memory which you've initialized with two 32-bit elements.  Here is what memory looks like in the 8-bit vs 32-bit case (all values represent 8-bit bytes):

After writing two 8-bit values to memory:

```
base+0x0: 0x1A
base+0x1: 0x10
```

After writing two 32-bit values to memory:

```
base+0x0: 0x1A 0x00 0x00 0x00
base+0x4: 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

So you can see that if the native code starts reading from `base`, the values it sees are significantly different depending on how you initialize the memory.

BTW, if the native code does *not* need to keep a reference to the memory you pass in longer than the function call itself, you can just use `byte[]` as the `UNUM8*` parameter, rather than allocating and initializing `Memory`.

Comment: Thanks technomage. Like you mentioned I did not even make a pointer to a byte[] as the native code does not need it beyond the function call scope. Its ok if its GC'd. Using byte[] directly worked as it is already a reference type. Thanks again for the detailed explanation and emphasis on datatypes against memory usage.